# JQuery: fire script inline with link

Tags: jquery

I think I may know what's causing some of the animation flicker on mobile Safari (backface styling reduced 90% of it but not all). I noticed that if you quickly tap the link on mobile safari it will flicker but if you press the link for a fraction of a second longer it never flickers. I think there is an issue with lag so I'd like to fire this script inline with the link itself. How is this done?

**Link in body**

```
<a href="" id="touchmenubutton"></a>
```

**Script at end of HTML document**

```
var touchMenuButton = $("#touchmenubutton");
var touchMenuCanvas = $("#touchmenucanvas");
var touchMenuDrawer = $("#touchmenudrawer");
touchMenuButton.on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    touchMenuCanvas.toggleClass("canvas-open");
    touchMenuDrawer.toggleClass("drawer-open drawer-closed");
    });
```

Comment: Yes, inline javascript is sure to help, it always makes stuff better.

Comment: Add the onclick="your code " to the link. But are you sure that's the way to go?

Comment: Do I understand that right, you want to call the link with javascript? like `$().on("click", function(e){ $.goTo("http://google.com"); });`

Comment: Is there a way to name my script and then embed that inline with the link in the HTML to fire that script on click?